# margin:auto; not adding a margin

Tags: css, margin

im playing around with a loading bar in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6BRn/9/), and i have this code

### html

```
<div id="back"><span id="text">loading...</span></div>
```

### css

```
#back {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#bbbbbb;
}

#text {
    z-index:2;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
}

div{
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

yet the `span` does not have a margin, it looks like this

[image: img]

when i give it a normal `margin` value it works.

i have also tried `margin: 0 auto;` but also with no success. and when i try `margin:10px auto;` i get the `10px` but not the `auto`.

Comment: Are you trying to center the "loading" text horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Why you don't want to make fixed margins?
I mean why to use Auto?

Comment: @Adrift @xryo @showdev i am trying to center `loading...`.

Comment: You want to center it in the red span or in the grey box no matter what the status is?

Comment: @xyro center of grey always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying auto margin to an absolutely positioned inline element with unknown width introduces various problems.

I had success centering the text by setting `line-height` and `text-align:center` like so:

```
#text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruzED/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the text is position absolute. Try this:

```
#back {
    width:100px;
    background-color:#bbbbbb;
    text-align:center;
}

#text {
    z-index:2;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6BRn/13/

Comment: still doesnt center it height-wise.

Comment: Try now. You can use line-height or margin.